# what does it mean when a name fascinates you

Tags: definition

I just wanted to know out of curiosity because I was wondering and I did not know what it is so can someone please explain it to me I don't know because no one has told me

Comment: If "X" fascinates a person, it would make that person feel fascinated towards "X"! What is ambiguous?

Comment: @Cardinal "towards" doesn't work with fascinated. One is fascinated **by** or **with** something, or one has a fascination **with** something.

Comment: @TypeIA Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One *fascinates* you when one catches your interest, or when one evokes an intense interest or attraction in you.

> **X fascinates you** ----->> X catches your interest. (X is irresistibly charming or attractive to you.)